# How can I change the allowed file types on Nextcloud?

Tags: nextcloud

We have a Nextcloud instance, and cannot upload .wav files. How can we configure Nextcloud to allow various file formats, such as .wav?

Comment: There is no limitation on the Nextcloud side to upload .wav files. Maybe you have configured the File Access Control app (https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/10/admin_manual/configuration_files/files_access_control.html#prevent-uploading-of-specific-files)? If not how are you uploading these files, using the Desktop Sync Client, Web, Android etc? Also can you post the contents of nextcloud.log and the web server error log.

Comment: FWIW, another person on Twitter messaged me saying they have this problem too: https://twitter.com/hannes_knutsson/status/972990168205492226

Comment: Also, this question has over 1,000 views, so something seems odd.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well (but additionally a not-anymore-existent file in the DB). I solved it either by running

```
occ files:scan
```

or by uploading one .wav file via the webinterface. I just don't know. It suddently started working.